# What is the variable scope in Meteor client side?

Tags: meteor, scope

Inside the standard `isClient` conditional I have a variable stored. Let's say I needed to access this from the `window`, where would it be located?

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  var people = new Meteor.Collection("people");
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Meteor client environment, every variable you declare without the `var` keyword is accessible on the global object which is `window`.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  people = new Meteor.Collection("people");
  console.log(window.people._name); // displays "people" in the console
}
```

Variables declared with the `var` keyword are file scoped, variables declared without the `var` keyword are application scoped.

On the client, the global scope is the `window` object, on the server, the global scope is the `global` object.

When you declare a global variable in both environments, a property with this name is declared both on the `window` object and the `global` object, these two properties are distinct, if you modify the client one, it won't impact the server one.

Comment: I would not say "incorrect" because if you ever use the collection only in this particular file then it is OK to have it file scoped, however collections are usually used in multiple places (and thus files) so this is why they are usually declared globally on both client and server environments.