# MeteorJS retrieve result in JS from previous function?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Using Meteor, I would like to be able to retrieve the results of a given template, in this case `location` and use it as a variable in another JS operation. The specific application of this is for APIs.

```
Template.myTemplate.onCreated(function(){
  this.location = new ReactiveVar();
  var self = this;
  $.getJSON('http://ip-api.com/json/?callback=?', function(lingo) {
    self.location.set(lingo.zip + ", " + lingo.city);
  });
});

Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  location: function(){
    return Template.instance().location.get();}
});
```

Using the code above, I get a response on the area assigned `{{location}}` in my HTML. Now, I would like to use the `{{location}}` value, convert it into a string, and use it as a variable named `cheddar`. So for instance:

```
Template.anotherTemplate.onCreated(function(){
  this.zangrief = new ReactiveVar();
  var self = this;
  var cheddar = Template.instance().location.get();
  $.getJSON('http://www.anotherapi'+cheddar+'myapikey', function(red) {
    self.zangrief.set(red.stuff);
  });
});
```

The point of this is to get my location using API #1, and use that to get relevant data in API #2. In this example, I have used the return helper code in `var cheddar` to retrieve the response that was in my first template, `{{location}}`. This does not work, so I would like to know how one goes about such a thing.

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is that `Template.instance()` refers to an instance of the current template. You have two named templates, each of which can have multiple instances. As @shershen points out in his answer, you need to create a variable in a scope that it shared by both templates. The most common solution to this is simply a `Session` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's on the Client side, then you can try to assign a value in regular JS way var myvar = XXX; and then it should be accessible in other templates via window.myvar

```
//begining of the file
var myvar;

//template 1
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  location: function(){
    myvar = Template.instance().location.get()
    return Template.instance().location.get();}
});
//template 2
Template.anotherTemplate.onCreated(function(){
  this.zangrief = new ReactiveVar();
  var self = this;
  var cheddar = window.myvar
  //etc
```

Check the [docs on namespaces](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/namespacing) and also this post: [What is the variable scope in Meteor client side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28868629/what-is-the-variable-scope-in-meteor-client-side)